# Why does FacebookSession::newAppSession()->validate() throw Exception 'Session has expired, or is not valid for this app'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('foo', 'bar');
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

try {
    $session->validate();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    print_r($ex);
}

?>
```

I provide the correct application info but it throws an error:

```
...Session has expired, or is not valid for this app...
```

Please help.

Comment: using the exact same setup with my application info, I get a "name lookup timed out" error. Not sure if these are bugs or what, as documentation is sketchy at best.

Comment: Did you substitute 'foo' and 'bar' with your app and secret? And yeah, from my point of view, the documentation sucks.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same exception.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a session based on the accessToken and thereafter validate the session. You can't just validate a session with just the appId and the secret (without knowing anything about the session itself).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a platform at "Settings" tab on your dashboard

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in older versions of php-sdk-v4. Upgrade your SDK and this should work.